# Can a Firebase Realtime Database persist data on web like Cloud Firestore?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, web-applications, offline-caching

I have a web app that uses a Realtime Database to store data. If I go offline while the database is connected, make changes, and reconnect, everything works as intended. However, I'm trying to make my web app work as a PWA. Right now, the database only works offline if the page goes online while being used. If you close the app fully while offline and open the app, it won't load.

I see that Cloud Firestore for web has the `enableIndexedDbPersistence()` method, which appears to do what I want, although obviously since it's for a different service I can't use it. I also see that Realtime Database for Android has `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true)`, but since its for Android I can't use it for a web app.

Is there a way to enable this functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase Realtime Database only supports disk persistence in its Android and iOS SDKs. There is no disk persistence in the JavaScript SDK for Firebase Realtime Database.

Also see:

- [Does Firebase JavaScript API catch-up with server when re-connected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32530190/does-firebase-javascript-api-catch-up-with-server-when-re-connected)